# Is there a way to "Listen in" to a Telnet stream?

Tags: php, telnet, fsockopen

I just want a simple way of seeing what the last two lines in the Telnet stream were. For instance, if you can imagine a Terminal window, I just want to be able to type a command, hit enter, then see what the response is. So far, I can execute the command, but I'm having trouble evaluating the response. Rather than just the two lines of response being returned, `stream_get_line` returns every line from the stream.

Can anyone suggest a function or possibly a better way to write it?

```
$con = @pfsockopen("10.30.96.55", 23, $errno, $errstr, 30);

fputs($con, "ipaddress get\r");

while (!feof($con)) { 
    $response = stream_get_line($con, 100, "\n"); 
} 

echo $response;
```

It may be that I don't completely understand `stream_get_line()`;  if I'm doing something dumb, someone please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more experimentation with `fgets()`, I have been able to achieve the desired affect.

Rather than:

```
while (!feof($con)) { 
    $response = stream_get_line($con, 100, "\n"); 
}
```

I used:

```
while (($buffer = fgets($con, 5)) !== false) {
    $total .= $buffer;
}
```